# KeyError: 'ItalicAngle'

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

If I try to import font_manager, I get this exception:

```
>>> from matplotlib import font_manager
Value error parsing header in AFM: ItalicAngle -11,31
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1325, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1312, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 993, in __init__
    self.afmlist = createFontList(self.afmfiles, fontext='afm')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 568, in createFontList
    prop = afmFontProperty(fpath, font)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 485, in afmFontProperty
    if font.get_angle() != 0 or name.lower().find('italic') >= 0:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/afm.py", line 526, in get_angle
    return self._header[b'ItalicAngle']
KeyError: 'ItalicAngle'
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: There is a broken afm file which uses `,` instead of `.`

I found the broken afm file like this:

```
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*afm' | xargs grep -i ItalicAngle | grep ,
/usr/share/fonts/Type1/Calibri-LightItalic.afm:ItalicAngle -11,31
```

The file `Calibri-LightItalic.afm` was broken. The value `-11,31` is wrong, it needs to be `-11.31`

Since matplotlib uses a cache, you might need to remove this file .matplotlib/fontList.cache to see the exception again.